# Eclipse C++ MinGW Issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I'm trying to install the cccfiles library for Eclipse, but I keep getting the following error:

```
11:24:49 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test     ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o Test.exe hello.o practice.o "-lC:\\C++\\cccfiles" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.2.0/../../../../x86_64 w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\C++\cccfiles
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

11:24:49 Build Finished (took 777ms)
```

I've googled every possible thing I could think of for the last two days and nothing has helped me.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, and please don't post links to images or code (links can go stale, making your question totally worthless).

Comment: Ooh whoops. It's fixed :)